# Entity Framework, randomly creating duplicate records

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity

I have a simple entity framework 6 code first from existing database project for my web application. When I save data sometimes it saves properly with only 1 record saved. However sometimes it saves 2, 3 5 records it appears random.

For simplicity sake I have the following 2 classes. One is a parent "Person", and "PersonAddress" is the child. In my application there will always be 2 child records to 1 parent. No more no less (dont ask why). Here are my classes which are bare bones.

```
[Table("Person")]
public partial class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int PersonID { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual ICollection<PersonAddress> PersonAddresses { get; set; }

}

 [Table("PersonAddress")]
 public partial class PersonAddress
 {
    [Key]
    public int PersonAddressID { get; set; }

    public int PersonID { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }

    public string City { get; set; }

    public string State { get; set; }

    public string Zipcode { get; set; }

}
```

Here is my DBContext class

```
public partial class MyDBContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDBContext()
        : base("name=MyDBContext")
    {

        //skips database initialization so it wont track changes and produce error, not needed for code first
        Database.SetInitializer<MyDBContext>(null);
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<PersonAddress> PersonAddresses { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().Property(x => x.PersonID).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        modelBuilder.Entity<PersonAddress>().Property(x => x.PersonAddressID).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

    }
}
```

//sample code

```
Person person =  new Person();
person.FirstName = "TestFName";
person.LastName = "TestLName";

List<PersonAddress> addresses = new List<PersonAddress>();

PersonAddress address1 = new PersonAddress();
address1.Address1 = "line1"
//etc
//etc
addresses.Add(address1);

PersonAddress address2 = new PersonAddress();
address1.Address2 = "line1"
//etc
//etc
addresses.Add(address2);

//now add addresses to Person
person.PersonAddresses = addresses;


using (var context = new MyDBContext())
            {



                context.Persons.Add(person);
                context.SaveChanges();
                obj.PersonID = obj.PersonID;

            }
```

What am I doing wrong, the data always gets saved and the child records are automatically added when I save the parent without issue. But as previously stated sometimes numerous sets of records are saved and I dont see any reason why. Thanks

Comment: can you post the table structure it created?

Comment: sorry meant to say it was code first from existing database, updated question.

Comment: Are the created records identical?

Comment: can't see any problem in your sample code, probably happens in other part of your code. one suggestion or maybe that's the cause: Never assign a collection. the collection should be immutable and initialized in constructor and only do add/remove to/from it.

Comment: As this is using existing db, its possible it is getting confused not following convention, can you add [ForeignKey("Person")] on PersonId in Address class

Comment: @pjobs - i will try that, but its properly adding the parent record and then  using that primary key as a foreign key in the child record without issue, so is there a reason why adding that would make a difference?

Comment: @Andrew , if it is adding identical records then my hunch was wrong, it may not be related to foreignkey issue.

Comment: @Saeb completely identical with a datetimestamp of about 2-3 sec difference

Comment: You mentioned 'sometimes', do you mean run the above code multiple times and it gives you different expectations? Or is there any other scenarios around?

Comment: @Andrew like salitio said you shouldn't be assigning to a collection, especially when you want to replace all existing items( it will not remove the old ones), just adds new ones

Comment: @salitio Correct, we have this web application in QA and 5 out of 10 times no issues. Than sometimes it will save duplicate records for 1 submission (timestamp varies by a few seconds). I have verified no other errors are occurring and have traced it down to EF.

Comment: so the breaking scenario is always "creating new person with two new addresses"? no batch creating, updating and other scenarios?

Comment: @salitio correct, always 2 addresses for each person. No other scenario is allowed. We are only doing an insert, really simple POC app.

Comment: @Andrew , going back to your question, when you say duplicate, is it also adding duplicate Persons or just Addresses? or it duplicates the whole set?

Comment: @pjobs The set is always the same so same Person with 2 Addresses, repeated with a slight timestamp difference. For each person there is always 2 addresses saved in the database.

Comment: @Andrew I am not sure how is your scenario, but if it is being executed for data migration or from other source through for loop, then I would either blame the data source or the looping logic.

Comment: need to look at your full code then

Comment: thanks both for help. @salitio you made me question if the issue was coming elsewhere. I isolated my entity framework code in a unit test and it was working as expected. This code is called from an MVC controller and I suspect my controller action may be getting invoked multiple times (though its random and cant explain it), but that is a separate post. I did however make some of the changes you mentioned as best practices.

Comment: @Scott any updates on this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using (var context = new MyDBContext())
{
     Person.PersonAdresses.add(addres1);
     Person.PersonAdresses.add(addres2);
     context.Entry(Person).State=EntityState.Added;
     context.SaveChanges();
};
```